# Odd behavior when initializing an array using a class member

Tags: c++, c++11

I found an oddity with initialization that I'm trying to wrap my head around. I understand that an array can be initialized to all default values by using `T[size] {}`, which seems to work in most cases, but doesn't seem to work when being initialized by a class member, as in:

```
class Hashtable {
    int *table;
    int size;

public:
    Hashtable() : size { 10 }, table { new int[size]{} } {
        for (int index = 0; index != size; ++index) { // size = 10
            cout << table[index] << endl; // this displays an uninitialized array??
        }
    }
};
```

If I try to initialize `table` with a literal, as in `table { new int[10] {} }`, all the items in the array are set to default (`0`). Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `size` will be initialized *after* table, due to their order of declaration. You need

```
class Hashtable 
{
    int size;
    int* table;
    ....
```

Data members are initialized in their order of declaration, not the order you place them in the constructor initialization list. A suitable warning level on a reasonable compiler would tell you about this.

Comment: Oh, that's crazy I would have never figured that out. +1

Comment: @sircodesalot: Your compiler should warn you about this if your warning level is high enough.

Comment: Apparently it isn't ... figuring out why not now.

Comment: Even if I crank up the warning level all the way up to 11, I just get a ton of warnings for other irrelevant stuff, but not for this issue. (Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: @sircodesalot: Ah, looks like VS doesn't have this warning, a shame. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2553854-c-compiler-should-warn-about-wrong-member-initia